# AuthorizeNetAIM Error when set to live

Tags: php, authorize.net

I have a POS that uses authorize.net for credit card transactions. Everything is doing well when it is in testmode but when we go live we got this errors:

```
     A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 22
    Filename: lib/AuthorizeNetAIM.php
    Line Number: 446
    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 23
    Filename: lib/AuthorizeNetAIM.php
    Line Number: 447
    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 24
    Filename: lib/AuthorizeNetAIM.php
    Line Number: 448
    A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 25
    Filename: lib/AuthorizeNetAIM.php
    Line Number: 449
```

I opened AuthorizeNetAIM.php
and this is the line of code:

```
        $this->fax                  = $this->_response_array[22];
        $this->email_address        = $this->_response_array[23];
        $this->ship_to_first_name   = $this->_response_array[24];
        $this->ship_to_last_name    = $this->_response_array[25];
        $this->ship_to_company      = $this->_response_array[26];
        $this->ship_to_address      = $this->_response_array[27];
        $this->ship_to_city         = $this->_response_array[28];
        $this->ship_to_state        = $this->_response_array[29];
        $this->ship_to_zip_code     = $this->_response_array[30];
        $this->ship_to_country      = $this->_response_array[31];
        $this->tax                  = $this->_response_array[32];
        $this->duty                 = $this->_response_array[33];
        $this->freight              = $this->_response_array[34];
        $this->tax_exempt           = $this->_response_array[35];
        $this->purchase_order_number= $this->_response_array[36];
        $this->md5_hash             = $this->_response_array[37];
        $this->card_code_response   = $this->_response_array[38];
        $this->cavv_response        = $this->_response_array[39];
        $this->account_number       = $this->_response_array[50];
        $this->card_type            = $this->_response_array[51];
        $this->split_tender_id      = $this->_response_array[52];
        $this->requested_amount     = $this->_response_array[53];
        $this->balance_on_card      = $this->_response_array[54];
```

Comment: disable all the offsets which causing error like this `//$this->fax   = $this->_response_array[22];` and see if your transaction pass through

Comment: reason you are getting the error you didn't define these offsets in your HTML form

Comment: i tried to disable all the offset but it wont give a response of the transaction_id from authorize.net

Comment: I still get the error even I define the offsets in my html form.

Comment: for `transaction_id from authorize.net` check your response file url set properly in live mode and check in your authorize setting that billing and shipping address same or not, i remember there is an option there, one thing i can tell you is Authorise is pain in the ass

Comment: Testmode disables all transaction processing.  Instead the gateway will validate the credentials as return success.  You can confirm if you receive a transaction ID of Zero, meaning there wasn't transaction recorded.

Comment: Do I have to configure something to my authorize account or  the problem is the authorize PHP API? All I need is to get a transaction_id from authorize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved.

I used `print_r` to display the array contents of `$this->_response_array`. It shows a response reason code of 87 and response reason text of "Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system."

I opened the authorize account to check the market type.
The product type is "Card Present" and the market type is "Retail".
To make things work. The market type should be set to 2.
I update the `AuthorizeNetAim.php` and below is my code:

```
     protected $_x_post_fields = array(
    "version" => "3.1", 
    "delim_char" => ",",
    "delim_data" => "TRUE",
    "relay_response" => "FALSE",
    "encap_char" => "|",
    "market_type" => "2",
    "device_type" => "8"
    );
```

But it still shows the error. So I use the below code:

```
     if(isset($this->_response_array[22]))
        {
            $this->fax                  = $this->_response_array[22];
            $this->email_address        = $this->_response_array[23];
            $this->ship_to_first_name   = $this->_response_array[24];
            $this->ship_to_last_name    = $this->_response_array[25];
            $this->ship_to_company      = $this->_response_array[26];
            $this->ship_to_address      = $this->_response_array[27];
            $this->ship_to_city         = $this->_response_array[28];
            $this->ship_to_state        = $this->_response_array[29];
            $this->ship_to_zip_code     = $this->_response_array[30];
            $this->ship_to_country      = $this->_response_array[31];
            $this->tax                  = $this->_response_array[32];
            $this->duty                 = $this->_response_array[33];
            $this->freight              = $this->_response_array[34];
            $this->tax_exempt           = $this->_response_array[35];
            $this->purchase_order_number= $this->_response_array[36];
            $this->md5_hash             = $this->_response_array[37];
            $this->card_code_response   = $this->_response_array[38];
            $this->cavv_response        = $this->_response_array[39];
            $this->account_number       = $this->_response_array[50];
            $this->card_type            = $this->_response_array[51];
            $this->split_tender_id      = $this->_response_array[52];
            $this->requested_amount     = $this->_response_array[53];
            $this->balance_on_card      = $this->_response_array[54];
        }
```